# error in sql syntax in insert query

Tags: php, mysql

Here `$user` is an associative array, how do I use it in a mysql query?
What is syntax error here?

```
  $sql= 'INSERT INTO users(username,password,contact_no,Pan_card_no) VALUES($user["username"], $user["password"], $user["contact_no"], $user["pan"]';
```

Comment: Which programming language is that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: PHP. Which can be clearly said from the OP "code".

Comment: Use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements and then you don't need to worry about it - and it would mean you're no longer using a deprecated library as well

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: as I don't know PHP at all that could be any other template language as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps you,

```
 $sql= 'INSERT INTO users (username,password,contact_no,Pan_card_no) VALUES("'.$user['username'].'", "'.$user['password'].'", "'.$user["contact_no"].'", "'.$user["pan"].'")';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $sql= "INSERT INTO users(username,password,contact_no,Pan_card_no) VALUES('".$user["username"]."', '".$user["password"]."', '".$user["contact_no"]."', '".$user["pan"]."')";
```

You not closed the bracket ")"

Answer (score 0):

When you define a string on PHP by using single quotes ( `'` ) then the $-notation of variables is *not* interpreted. So the final sql statement still contains the `$` characters. This is not valid sql.

Instead create your statement like this:

```
sprintf('INSERT INTO users(username,password,contact_no,Pan_card_no) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)',
        $user['username'], $user['password'], $user['contact_no'], $user['pan']);
```

Note however that this smells of sql injections. You should use prepared statements instead for better security. Use the PDO or the mysqli extensions of PHP.

Comment: now its giving
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: The command is correct, you must have made a copy and paste error.